# Placeholder-shown weird behaviour with type=number - Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Using the `:placeholder-shown` attribute on an input tag, selects the state when the placeholder text is *visible*. This works as expected on Google Chrome with text input boxes and number input boxes.

**Google Chrome:**

[image]

Firefox seems to *ignore* this property when used on an `<input type=number>` field

**Firefox:**

[image]

**Question:** Why does this occur and how can it be overcome?

## Demo snippet

```css
input:placeholder-shown {
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="example">
<input placeholder="example" value="12345">
<br>
<input placeholder="example" type="number">
<input placeholder="example" type="number" value="12345">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `:placeholder-shown`  is not supported in firefox on type="number", type="time", and similar.

Here is the [**refrence**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown)

But you can work around it by using `::-moz-placeholder`

**See code below:**

```css
input:placeholder-shown {
    background: #000;
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
  background: #000;
  color: #ddd;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="example">
<input placeholder="example" value="12345">
<br>
<input placeholder="example" type="number">
<input placeholder="example" type="number" value="12345">
```

Comment: Seems to work now without prefix: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown#Result_4